# Increase client_max_body_size on Aws Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-config

Sources: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Linux 2 .NET Core API

After receiving the 413 Request Entity Too Large error, I made researches for a solution. Everything works when I connect into the machine with ssh and do client_max_body_size 20M with the **nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf** command.

But when a new deploy comes, it goes back to the old one.

With my research, I created **.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf** files in the root directory of the project.

proxy.conf content:

```
client_max_body_size 1024M;
```

I also created the **.platform/00_myconf.config** file.

00_myconf.config content:

```
container_commands:
   01_reload_nginx:
     command: "service nginx reload"
```

I keep getting the same error (413 Request Entity Too Large) when I upload and deploy after adding these.

By connecting to the machine with ssh
I can't find the max_body_size line in the file with the nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf command.

Answer (score 1):

This is old and hopefully you figured it out already.

If not, the reason you can't find the client_max_body_size line is that it isn't there by default, you have to add it.

ssh into the instance then:

```
cd /etc/nginx/conf.d/
sudo nano proxy.conf
```

paste in:

```
client_max_body_size 1024M;
```

and save and exit.

finally run:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Unfortunately the files stored on ec2 are ephemeral and will be lost on each deploy or if an instance goes down. As yet I have not been able to find an in-code solution for dotnet, but will update when I do.

Edit: Okay so in code solution (ie, not dependent on EC2 ephemeral storage):

Make a file in /.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf with the content:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Make sure in properties on Visual Studio that Copy to output directory is set to "Always" for this file and that the build action is "content."

Comment: See the edit I provided several weeks ago, it is in an in-code solution that won't be dependent on the ephemeral storage behind the EC2 instance. It gets written in on deployment of the instance. You don't need to perform additional maintenance. I have this deployed for production ASG. I've edited the answer again to make that more clear, kindly read the full answer.

Comment: That is literally the answer I gave you! The elastickbeanstalk directory is not necessary

Comment: I tried the solution a lot without the elastic beanstalk folder didn't work

Comment: Wow, that's really weird. Anyone else reading this, you don't need that part. Glad I could help.

Comment: I was also thinking, the reason for needing the elasticbeanstalk directory is probably due to us using different Amazon Linux 2 versions

Comment: I use .NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2.1.2. You?

Comment: It is the same except v 2.1.5, so I wouldn't think there was a difference. Who knows.

Comment: I'm running 2.2.2 and its not working. The comments here mention `\elasticbeanstalk\` but can't see that in the posts, so assume to ignore this?

Comment: @peter.swallow Hi Peter, did you try the path in the edit? (/.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf)

Comment: @Shaun turned out our problem was the line endings were set to Windows, rather than Linux which is what AWS was using, so it kept blowing up.

Comment: @peter.swallow Ah yeah that makese sense, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

This morning I had this issue that finally found out that I forgot to add `.platform` folder to GitLab CI/CD for publish. Re-check and make sure it's published.